# código window.matchMedia

Tags: javascript-objeto

Buen dia,necesito al realizar una consulta que verifique varios parámetros porque el código que empleo únicamente realiza en uno (700px),adjunto codigo para un mejor entendimiento.

```
function myFunction(x) {
  if (x.matches) { // If media query matches
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  } else {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
  }
}

var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)")
myFunction(x) // Call listener function at run time
x.addListener(myFunction) // Attach listener function on state changes
```

Comment: ¿Y qué mas quieres verificar?, ¿qué has intentado?, por favor lee [ask]

Answer (score 0):

```
//Verificar si existe.
if (window.matchMedia) {

var mql = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 700px)');
//Registrar evento.
mql.addEventListener( "change", function(e) {
  if (e.matches) {
   // la pantalla <= 700px
  } else {
   // mayor > 700px
  }
});

}
```